# How correctly use Keys?

Tags: flutter, key, tabbar

How to correctly using Keys? I need saving state of my widgets with title(title can dynamic change i use TextField Widget)but when i delete some current Tab deleted last Tab.

```
      class _ChangedTabBarState extends State<ChangedTabBar> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
    
    
      List<Widget> _tabNameList = [];
    
      List<Widget> _tabViewList = [];
    
      List data;
    
      TabController _tabController;

  void _addNewTab(){
    _tabNameList.add(StatefulTab(title: null,));
    _tabViewList.add(Text((_tabController.length + 1).toString()));
    setState(() {
      this._tabController = TabController(length: _tabViewList.length, vsync: this);
    });
  }
  void _deleteTab(){
    int index = _tabController.index;
    _tabViewList.removeAt(index);
    _tabNameList.removeAt(index);
    //_tabNameList[index] = Text("removing");
    setState(() {
      this._tabController = TabController(length: _tabViewList.length, vsync: this);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              indicatorColor: textColor,
              labelColor: textColor,
              isScrollable: true,
              labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 45.0),
              unselectedLabelColor: textLightColor ,
              tabs: _tabNameList.toList()
            ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: padding),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  children: _tabViewList.toList()
              ),
            ),
            isRoot ? 
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () => _addNewTab(),),
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.remove), onPressed: () => _deleteTab(),)
                ],
              ) : SizedBox(height: 0, width: 0,)
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

this is my dynamic Tab

```
class StatefulTab extends StatefulWidget {


  final String title;

  StatefulTab({Key key, @required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StatefulTabState createState() => _StatefulTabState(title);
}

class _StatefulTabState extends State<StatefulTab> {

  String _title;

  _StatefulTabState(this._title){
    print(_title.toString() + "  init");
  }


  TextEditingController _textController;

  bool _errorText = false;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _textController = TextEditingController(text: _title);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _textController.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("TITLE in build: " + _title.toString());
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Container(color: Colors.transparent, child: Tab(child: Text(_title == null ? "Catalog Name" : _title,style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Times New Roman',fontSize: 16.0,)),),),
      onLongPress: (){
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          child: Dialog(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  key: ValueKey(_title),
                  controller: _textController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Write new name", errorText: _errorText ? "Write correct name" : null),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Save"),
                  onPressed: (){
                    setState(() {
                      _errorText = _textController.text.replaceAll(" ", "") == "";
                      if(!_errorText) _title = _textController.text;
                    });
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

How can I change my array that stores instances of dynamically changing Tabs without changing their states? In the class of changing Tabs itself there is a text field and a state - "_titile", when you try to delete the tag, the TabBarView body itself is deleted correctly and is in the correct position relative to remote objects, but the name of the tab itself is displayed incorrectly.